# Errors in referencing a particular node in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, nodes, vba

I'm trying to import exchange rates into my worksheet, but I'm having trouble parsing the xml from the RSS feed from the Bank of Canada

So my some of my XML document looks like this

```
<item rdf:about="http://www.bankofcanada.ca/stats/assets/rates_rss/noon/en_SEK_NOON.xml">
    <title xml:lang="en">CA: 6.5402 SEK_NOON = 1 CAD 2015-11-24 Bank of Canada noon rate</title>
    <link>http://www.bankofcanada.ca/?page_id=39919</link>
    <description xml:lang="en">1 Canadian Dollar = 6.5402 SEK_NOON (SEK_NOON = Swedish krona). These are the Bank of Canada's nominal noon exchange rates, published at about 12:30 ET each business day. These are neither buying nor selling rates, and should be used for reference purposes only.</description>
    <dc:date>2015-11-24T12:30:00-05:00</dc:date>
    <dc:language>en</dc:language>
    <cb:statistics>
        <cb:country>CA</cb:country>
        <cb:exchangeRate>
            <cb:value decimals="2">6.5402</cb:value>
            <cb:baseCurrency>CAD</cb:baseCurrency>
            <cb:targetCurrency>SEK_NOON</cb:targetCurrency>
            <cb:rateType>Bank of Canada noon rate</cb:rateType>
            <cb:observationPeriod frequency="daily">2015-11-24T12:30:00-05:00</cb:observationPeriod>
        </cb:exchangeRate>
    </cb:statistics>
</item>
<item rdf:about="http://www.bankofcanada.ca/stats/assets/rates_rss/noon/en_CHF_NOON.xml">
    <title xml:lang="en">CA: 0.7635 CHF_NOON = 1 CAD 2015-11-24 Bank of Canada noon rate</title>
    <link>http://www.bankofcanada.ca/?page_id=39919</link>
    <description xml:lang="en">1 Canadian Dollar = 0.7635 CHF_NOON (CHF_NOON = Swiss franc). These are the Bank of Canada's nominal noon exchange rates, published at about 12:30 ET each business day. These are neither buying nor selling rates, and should be used for reference purposes only.</description>
    <dc:date>2015-11-24T12:30:00-05:00</dc:date>
    <dc:language>en</dc:language>
    <cb:statistics>
        <cb:country>CA</cb:country>
        <cb:exchangeRate>
            <cb:value decimals="4">0.7635</cb:value>
            <cb:baseCurrency>CAD</cb:baseCurrency>
            <cb:targetCurrency>CHF_NOON</cb:targetCurrency>
            <cb:rateType>Bank of Canada noon rate</cb:rateType>
            <cb:observationPeriod frequency="daily">2015-11-24T12:30:00-05:00</cb:observationPeriod>
        </cb:exchangeRate>
    </cb:statistics>
</item>
```

and I'm trying to extract the exchange value. using my code I am able to extract the node exchangeRate and I want to get the value and targetCurrency nodes from that parent node. However I seem to have trouble getting them

```
 Sub ParseXML()
 Dim feedresult As String

 Dim xDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
     feedresult = GetHTTPResponse("http://www.bankofcanada.ca/stats/assets/rates_rss/noon/en_all.xml")
Set xDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
xDoc.LoadXML (feedresult)

Dim currList As IXMLDOMNodeList
Set currList = xDoc.getElementsByTagName("cb:exchangeRate")

Dim currNode As IXMLDOMNode
Dim childNode As IXMLDOMNode

For Each currNode In currList
    exchangeRate = currNode.SelectSingleNode("value").Text
    Debug.Print exchangeRate
Next currNode
End Sub
```

However I constantly get a Run Time Error 91 Object variable or With block not set

I know that the basename of the inner node is value as I have interated through the baseName of the childnodes of exchangeRate. If I use the following code, then I achieve what I want

```
For Each childNode In currNode.ChildNodes
        If childNode.BaseName = "targetCurrency" Then
            tc = Left(childNode.Text, 3)
        End If
        If childNode.BaseName = "value" Then
            exchangeRate = childNode.Text
        End If
Next childNode
```

However I realise this is a very inelegant solution and I should be able to reference the child nodes by their basenames.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: Isn't the syntax `exchangeRate = currNode.SelectSingleNode("value").InnerText`?

Comment: Scratch that. I'm incorrect.

Comment: Try it with the namespace added: `currNode.SelectSingleNode("cb:value").Text`

Comment: I tried it with the namespace added and it came up with a Runtime error: "Reference to undeclared namespace"